# How to dynamically deserialize generic class with multiple occurances of T

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize instances of a generic class while preserving the generic types, so I will be able to deserialize it later without having to specify the generic type manually.

I understand that the usual way of deserializing generic objects is by using type references or `JavaType` objects like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader or = om.reader();
ObjectWriter ow = om.writer();

String json = "[1, 2, 3]"
JavaType listType = or.getTypeFactory()
                      .constructParametricType(List.class, Integer.class);
List<Integer> integers = or.forType(listType).readValue(json)
```

But I do not know the generic type (`Integer` in this case) beforehand, therefore I can't do this.

I also understand that, because of erasure, I'll have to include the type information within the serialized JSON in some way or another. This can be done with the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation:

```
class Pojo<T> {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    public T value;
}
```

However, this quickly becomes bloated if the type `T` is used in various other places. Consider the following example:

```
class Pojo<T> {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    public T value;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    public List<T> otherStuff;
    // constructor
}
// ...
Pojo<BigDecimal> pojo = new Pojo<>(
    BigDecimal.valueOf(42),
    Lists.newArrayList(BigDecimal.valueOf(14), BigDecimal.valueOf(23))
);
final String json = ow.writeValueAsString(pojo);
System.out.println(json);
```

produces the following result:

```
{
    "value": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 42],
    "otherStuff":[
        ["java.math.BigDecimal", 14],
        ["java.math.BigDecimal", 23]
    ]
}
```

which repeats the type, `BigDecimal` in this case, for every single object. This is unnecessary because the type is the same for all occurances of `T` anyway (except in some polymorphic cases I suppose).

If the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation is omitted for `otherStuff`, Jackson is unable to defer the type of the contents of `otherStuff` from the type of `value`. In this example it will deserialize `otherStuff` as `List<Integer>`, even though `value` is of type `BigDecimal`.

How can I serialize instances of a generic class, so that I can safely deserialize them later and retain the generic argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type information indeed needs to be included in the serialized json string, but only once. The easiest way I know of is to write a custom creator method using the `@JsonCreator` annotation to perform the deserialization in two steps:

1. Let Jackson deserialize all non-generic fields, and one generic field that includes the type information. Capture the other generic fields as raw `JsonNode`, so they can be manually deserialized.
2. Take that type information at runtime to deserialize the remaining fields.

For the example above this would look like this (exception handling code omitted):

```
class Pojo<T> {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    public T value;
    public List<T> otherStuff;
    // constructor

    @JsonCreator
    public static <T> Pojo<T> jsonCreator(
            @JsonProperty("value") T value,
            @JsonProperty("otherStuff") JsonNode otherStuffRaw) {
        JavaType listType = or.getTypeFactory()
                              .constructParametricType(List.class, value.getClass());
        return new Pojo<T>(
            value,
            or.forType(listType).readValue(otherStuffRaw)
        );
    }
}
```

This, however, allows `value` to be a subclass of `T`, which might produce unexpected results. If this is a concern, another approach might be using `Class<T>` to retain the exact type of `T`. This would also shield against `value` possibly being `null`.